Bathing and marriage in ancient Greek culture
Early on in Homer's Odyssey, the maiden princess of the seafaring peoples is called by the goddess to go and bathe on the beach and wash clothes with her servants. This is understood both by the goddess and by her parents to have some connection with her impending marriage. What is this connection? Is this an ancient Greek cultural practice, or am I missing something in the text?

I think "wear nice clothes at a wedding" isn't especially particular to the ancient Greeks, as a cultural practice :)

One translation (The Odyssey with an English Translation by A.T. Murray, PH.D. in two volumes)

Nausicaa, how comes it that thy mother bore thee so heedless? Thy bright raiment is lying uncared for; yet thy marriage is near at hand, when thou must needs thyself be clad in fair garments, and give other such to those who escort thee. It is from things like these, thou knowest, that good report goeth up among men, and the father and honored mother rejoice.

She has to attend to the laundry simply to look fine at her wedding and give good garments to others, because it would be unfitting for a princess otherwise.

Book 6 of the Odyssey seems to be organized in the form of a marriage of Nausicaa and Odysseus—not a real wedding, but the individual steps of a wedding, in play or mock. There are several theories about the reason for this, which I will discuss after going through the parallels.
Athena (disguised as the daughter of Dymas) reminds Nausicaa that she is to be married: “thou shalt not long remain a maiden. Even now thou hast suitors in the land, the noblest of all the Phaeacians” (6.33–35, translated by A. T. Murray). Everyone wishes to look their best on the wedding-day, and so the wedding-clothes must be laundered: Athena says, “Thy bright raiment is lying uncared for; yet thy marriage is near at hand, when thou must needs thyself be clad in fair garments, and give other such to those who escort thee” (6.26–28). The word that Murray translates as “bright” is σιγαλόεντα (glossy, glittering), an epic word (that is, rare outside of epic poetry) suggesting a wedding dress.
Nausicaa has to request the wherewithal for a laundry expedition, under the excuse that this is so that Alcinous can have clean clothes “when thou art at council with the princes” (6.61) since she is “ashamed to name gladsome marriage to her father; but he understood all” (6.66–67).
Once the laundry is done, the bride and groom must wash and adorn themselves: Nausicaa and her maidens “bathed and anointed themselves richly with oil” (6.96), and later Odysseus “washed his whole body and anointed himself with oil” (6.227) and Athena “made his locks to flow in curls like unto the hyacinth flower” (6.231).
The groom addresses the bride with fair words: “But he again is blessed in heart above all others, who shall prevail with his gifts of wooing and lead thee to his home” (6.158–159), the bride lifts her veil to reveal her face: “she and her handmaids, they threw off their head-gear” (6.99–100), and finally the groom approaches the bride naked: “Odysseus came forth from beneath the bushes, and with his stout hand he broke from the thick wood a leafy branch, that he might hold it about him and hide therewith his nakedness” (6.127–129).
Nausicaa’s marriage is further alluded to in line 180, where Odysseus tells her “may the gods grant thee all that thy heart desires; a husband and a home may they grant thee”, line 244 where Nausicaa tells her maidens “Would that a man such as he [Odysseus] might be called my husband”, and line 277, where Nausicaa tells Odysseus that “some baser fellow” might say, “Who is this that follows Nausicaa, a comely man and tall, a stranger? Where did she find him? He will doubtless be a husband for her.” And in book 7, Alcinous tells Odysseus, “I would that thou, so goodly a man, and like-minded with me, wouldst have my daughter to wife, and be called my son, and abide here.” But nothing comes of this, and Nausicaa has to bid Odysseus “Farewell, stranger, and hereafter even in thy own native land mayest thou remember me, for to me first thou owest the price of thy life” (8.461–462).
So, what is the purpose of this mock-marriage, when it seemingly leads nowhere? No-one knows for sure! J. B. Hainsworth suggested that the Nausicaa episode is a relic of an older story:

There is no hint in the text of Odysseus’ being detained, or desiring to remain, on Scheria with an amorous princess or her matchmaking parents, as he was detained by Calypso […] It is likely that the marriage (and some other elements such as the games in viii) is mentioned because the poet is familiar with a folk-tale in which an unprepossessing suitor outwits glamorous but unworthy rivals, only to be revealed as a prince in disguise.
J. B. Hainsworth (1988). Comment on Odyssey 2.27. In Alfred Heubeck, Stephanie West, and J. B. Hainsworth (1988). A Commentary on Homer’s Odyssey, volume 1, page 295. Oxford: Clarendon.

Hainsworth refers us to W. J. Woodhouse, who wrote, I am not sure on what evidential basis, that:

The Odyssey is largely, but not entirely, a congeries of old stories, folk-tales of immemorial antiquity. One of these stories is that of a castaway who comes on the scene in wretched guise, a mere wreck, or man of no account. In the sequel he is revealed in his true character, as a prince, fore most in manly exercises, in which he defeats all rivals, and wins the prize of marriage with the daughter of the king to whose land he has come thus incognito. In a more sophisticated age, this type of story takes a thousand different forms; it is a very Proteus among stories. It tends to place the emphasis upon character—beneath a rugged or forbidding exterior the testing of circumstances reveals a heart of gold, as the phrase goes, while the showy or fair exterior is shown to be a cloak for poltroonery or downright villainy. This story is clearly discernible in the Odyssey. It constitutes a central episode in the poem—that of Odysseus at the court of king Alkinoos.
W. J. Woodhouse (1930). The Composition of Homer’s Odyssey, pages 54–55. Oxford: Clarendon.

But Norman Austin pointed out that the Odyssey is very concerned with marriage, past, present and future—the threatened marriage of Penelope and a suitor, the double marriage of Hermione to Neoptolemus and Megapenthes to the daughter of Alector, the marriage of Menelaus and Helen, the desire of Calypso to marry Odysseus, the mock-marriage of Odysseus with Nausicaa and, finally, the true marriage of Odysseus and Penelope. The mock-marriage in book 6, he says, prefigures the true marriage (or reunion of spouses) in book 23:

The poet has presented himself with an interesting challenge: though the poem unfolds inexorably toward marriage there will be, in fact, no wedding, since the principals in this case are already husband and wife. The wedding, which will conclude the poem, must therefore be a simulacrum, and if that high moment is only make-believe, why not multiply the simulacra? Introducing Nausicaa into the plot allows the poet to replicate not only the wedding ceremonies but, more significantly, the simulated bride. While Odysseus will simulate the groom in both instances the functions of the bride will be given in the first instance to the virgin with adolescent yearnings, easily infatuated, whose innocence will allow her a certain forwardness. But then she will be replaced by the older and shrewder woman, and the simulated courtship will be that much more challenging.
Norman Austin (1991) ‘The Wedding Text in Homer’s Odyssey’. In Arion: A Journal of Humanities and the Classics, third series, 1:2, page 237.

The boldest suggestion is that of Samuel Butler, that the Odyssey was written by a woman, and that Nausicaa is the poet’s self-portrait. If this were the case, we could interpret the mock-marriage in book 6 as an idealized depiction of the poet’s own courtship and wedding.

When I came to the Phæacian episode I felt sure that here at any rate the writer was drawing from life, and that Nausicaa, Queen Arete, and Alcinous were real people more or less travestied […] As soon as the idea that the writer was a woman—and a young one—presented itself to me, I felt that here was the reading of the riddle that had so long baffled me. I tried to divest myself of it, but it would not go […] it was a long time before I came to see that the poem was all of it written at Trapani, and that the writer had introduced herself into her work under the name of Nausicaa.
Samuel Butler (1897). The Authoress of the Odyssey, chapter 1. Project Gutenberg.


Your last remarks were a complete surprise to me! Thank you!

@paulgarrett Robert Graves wrote a novel, Homer's Daughter (1955) based on Butler's theory.
